# copying a 24x24 image into a 28x28 array of zeros

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Hi I want to copy a random portion of a 28x28 matrix and then use the resulting 24x24 matrix to be inserted into a 28x28 matrix 
        image = image.reshape(28, 28)

```
    getx = random.randint(0,4)
    gety = random.randint(0,4)

    # get a 24 x 24 tile from a random location in img
    blank_image = np.zeros((28,28), np.uint8)

    tile= image[gety:gety+24,getx:getx+24]
    cv2.imshow("the 24x24 Image",tile)
```

tile is a 24x24 ROI works as planned

```
    blank_image[gety:gety+24,getx:getx+24] = tile
```

blank_image in my example does not get updated with the values from tile

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating a submatrix of Mat in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664097/updating-a-submatrix-of-mat-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting an error, it might be because your np array dimensions are different. If your image is an RGB image, then your blank image should be defined as :

```
blank_image = np.zeros((28,28,3), uint8)
```